# Banner Image not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, banner

I have vertical side menu bar with collapse/open option. When we closes the sidebar, slider image get resized and occupy full width of screen accordingly. It is working perfectly on desktop.

But on mobile devices, full banner image is not showing. Some part of image is shown. I want to resize image and show full image and not the part of it.

I have tried with `width` attribute, `background-size` option with value cover / contain. But not working. With contain value, full image is seen on mobile but then there is huge white space (around 100 px) above and below image.

Following is the html and css code.

**HTML Code :**

```
 <!-- Banner -->
        <section class="main-banner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="banner-content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="banner-caption">
                        <h4>Hello, this is your <em>Website</em> Theme.</h4>
                        <span>AWESOME HTML5 &amp; CSS3 TEMPLATE</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                        <div class="primary-button">
                          <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

**CSS is as follows :**

```
/* Banner */

.main-banner .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.main-banner .banner-content {
    background-image: url(../images/main-banner.jpg);   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}

.main-banner .banner-content .banner-caption {
    max-width: 450px;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.0);
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.main-banner .banner-content .banner-caption h4 {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #31323a;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity:0;
}

.main-banner .banner-content .banner-caption em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: #DB214C;
    opacity:0;
}

.main-banner .banner-content .banner-caption span {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    opacity:0;
}

.main-banner .banner-content .banner-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

I don't need banner-caption, so it can be removed....

Your valuable help is appreciated.

**A Sample [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beotpxfr/)**

Here you can see image by resizing preview pane

Comment: Try creating a demo on JSfiddle, so that it would helpful to replicate your issue.

Comment: Did you try to set by using `media quires`

Comment: @Awais Yes, I tried background-size:contain; with media query instead of background-size:cover; But didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please create a snippet of your code

Comment: I don't really understand your problem here. If you want that the background has 100% it will cause: 1. streching when the height is also 100% or 2. white space on bellow and above the image when the height is auto

Comment: @uday8486 I have added sample jsfiiddle in my question. You can see preview  pane for image visibility by resizing it.

Comment: @Awais I have added sample jsfiiddle in my question. You can see preview  pane for image visibility by resizing it. I want full image in view and not part of it...

Comment: Well in that case you need to compromise between two the full size of image as contain or cove will cut them image. so the best is use media quires and use `background-size` in `% ` to set the best

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .main-banner .banner-content {
    background-image: url(../images/main-banner.jpg);   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:center center;
    }
}
```

this could be work

Comment: It worked with background-size:100% 50%; But then there is huge blank space below image...around 100px

Comment: @DrJManish background-size:100% 50%; means the width of the background is set to 100% and the height to 50% of the element, so the other 50% of the height would be transparent.

Comment: @RickyStefano Yes you are right... but with background-size:100% 100%; image get stretched vertically.. How can we fix it ?

Comment: You have to change image-size or reduce height value i don't know any other way for cover image quality maybe you can use srcset